# What are the minimal chemical requirements for a food which we all can eat?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've been puzzled by the following though experiment for the past few days:

I want to make my own food from scratch, but I do not know where to start from.
I want to be 100% sure that what I eat will never contains something that can damage my body. For example: If you buy something from the local market you can not be 100% sure that it's safe to eat. (99.9 % maybe... but that's not 100%)

I want to ask you to tell me, how can I make a food that I can eat, or should I say - live on it, for the rest of my life, that's 100% safe, I can control every aspect of it's creation and has many combinations of taste because I love diversity.

Thank you for your time : )

Edit:
Because I realized my question is very broad and indeed is a little... too much scientific I want to close it. But before I do so, here's what I had in mind:
I wanted to take some chemical elements, put them in a jar, run some electricity, heat, whatever through it, filter it, do some additional processing and eat it.
 I wanted to know if the stomach can take it, because I was going to eat food that's not hard to digest.

Comment: Can you please work on your question? You want to know which food is sufficient to live from only?

Comment: Does it sound better now?

Comment: "I want to be 100% sure that what I eat will never contains something that can damage my body" Our current knowledge in nutrition in order to know such thing.

Comment: Your question seems to be mixing marketing and cultural references and from this asking for an objective response. It sounds like you want to know how to eat healthy. This isn't really a question of how biology works. Is your base question: What sources of chemical fuel do humans metabolize?

Comment: This question is very broad and can not be answered without a very high degree of opinion and assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the three basic biomolecules used by the body are carbohydrates, lipids, and proteins, you would need to consume these three molecules only. Now we can choose three substances.

1. Glucose, one of the most basic carbohydrates, is needed for ATP production, so that would be a food choice there.
2. Any oil or butter will provide lipids.
3. Protein comes from a variety of sources. Meat is typically though of as the best, but nuts are a pretty good source too.

Since nuts satisfy proteins and lipids, I'd say honey roasted peanuts are the most basic food you could live off of, if you replace pure glucose for the honey.

Comment: This seems to the closest to my expectations regarding the answer, thank you : )